# `file`, why executables not reported as executables?

Tags: linux, gcc, debian

In GNU/Linux Debian 9.9 (stretch) my program is reported as:

```
build/debug/program_g:              ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=be082fb3..., not stripped
build/debug/stripped_program_g:     ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=be082fb3..., stripped
build/release/program:              ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6477469..., stripped
build/release/program_not_stripped: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6477469..., not stripped
```

Compiler is GCC (vanilla distro's i.e. `gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 2017051`), flags are for "release":

```
 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wunused-result -Wmissing-include-dirs 
 -Wparentheses -std=c89 -DPROGRAM_USE_STD_C89 -O2 -DNDEBUG
```

For "debug":

```
 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wunused-result -Wmissing-include-dirs 
 -Wparentheses -std=c89 -DPROGRAM_USE_STD_C89 -O0 -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -DTRACE_U0 -DTRACE_U1 -no-pie
```

Question is why for "release" the executable is reported as `shared object`instead of `executable`?

Comment: Strange. Compiling with your `"release"` options on both openSUSE (gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.4.1) and Archlinux (gcc (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1)) both report `"ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=...., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped"` -- so something is strange. Are you using Automake scripts, a Makefile, or just launching gcc with the options above?

Comment: I normally use Autotools, but that's exceptionally a handwritten Makefile, for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

**1.** You're using the `-no-pie` option with your "debug" build. Building position independent executables (`-pie`) is the default on recent Linux distros. Why are you disabling it in debug builds?

**2.** The `file` program on your system (Debian stretch) doesn't know about PIE executables. Newer versions of its magic files will correctly identify it as `pie executable`.

Example (`/mnt/old` is a Debian 9.9 root fs):

```
$ cc -xc - <<<'int main(){}'

$ file -m /mnt/old/usr/share/misc/magic a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=df3780407016f3ea1a936c35d786288b1c0d4486, not stripped

$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=df3780407016f3ea1a936c35d786288b1c0d4486, not stripped
```

Comment: From VCS annotate: [https://hastebin.com/xakalulifa.pl](https://hastebin.com/xakalulifa.pl). 

Comment: Oh no, hastebin's [paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021719/file-why-executables-not-reported-as-executables#comment107967102_61022428) went away! I should paste the reason again.

Comment: In short, above `-no-pie` addition there's a note - _added while fighting an issue related to `gprof`, it probably can go away_.